How to implement HDBSCAN clustering in java android
I want to implement HDBscan algorithm to the java android app. I am porting C# to java. In C# they were done using a library named Hdbscansharp. I tried with ELKI in java but I couldn't succeed. the original C# code is
   double avgTgtSpd = (tgt1.speed + tgt2.speed) / 2;
   filteredHits.Add(new FilteredHit(avgTgtDist, avgTgtSpd, currTgtDirection)); 
   aggregateSpeed += avgTgtSpd;


   // HDBSCAN Clustering
  double[][] twoDfilteredHits = filteredHits.Select(hit => new double[] { hit.pos 
  }).ToArray();  // put filtered hits in format hdbscan lib can use
HdbscanResult hdbscanResult = HdbscanRunner.Run(new HdbscanParameters<double[]>
{
   DataSet = twoDfilteredHits.ToArray(),
   MinPoints = 3,  
   MinClusterSize = 4
   DistanceFunction = new HdbscanSharp.Distance.ManhattanDistance()
  });

I was able to port the code till "twoDfilter" in java, but got stuck in implementation of HDBSCan.
How to get the "hdbscanResult" in java?
